# Keras to_json(), what does it save?

Tags: python, json, keras

My impression is that it only saves the model's architecture, so I should be able to call it before I start training? And then `save_weights()` saves the weights I need to restore the model? Any more details on this?

At what stage can I call `to_json()`? I.e. do I have to call `compile()` first? Can it be before `fit()` ?

Comment: The [keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) is quite extensive on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [Keras docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#savingloading-only-a-models-architecture) it only saves the architecture of the model:

> #### Saving/loading only a model's architecture
>
> If you only need to save the architecture of a model, and not its
>   weights or its training configuration, you can do:
>
> ```
> # save as JSON
> json_string = model.to_json()
>
> # save as YAML
> yaml_string = model.to_yaml()
> ```
>
> The generated JSON / YAML files are human-readable and can be manually
>   edited if needed.
>
> You can then build a fresh model from this data:
>
> ```
> # model reconstruction from JSON:
> from keras.models import model_from_json
> model = model_from_json(json_string)
>
> # model reconstruction from YAML
> from keras.models import model_from_yaml
> model = model_from_yaml(yaml_string)
> ```

Comment: At what stage can I call to_json()? I.e. do I have to call .compile() first? Can it be before fit() ?

Comment: @BaronYugovich You can call it after or before calling `compile` method. It does not make any difference as it does not save the training configurations (e.g. loss function or optimizer used).